# Should an object set its own attributes within the constructor?

Tags: object, attributes, constructor

I'm wondering in general terms whether an Object should set itself based on one parameter in the constructor. For example: If in the constructor you specify the objects ID, should the object itself then set its own variables by fetching the other data from the database? Or, should another class be created explicitly for creating this object, which would then hide the database from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my recommendations

1. Use an ObjectFactory pattern to this construction based on an ID. Anything that starts to resemble a recipe, an ObjectFactory patterns works best.
2. I don't suggest using a dependency on a database inside a constructor of an Object. You can put this data loading logic in the ObjectFactory as well.

Basically, I feel that the implementation of a class should be as lean as possible.

Comment: Would you create an object factory for each individual object? Or, one factory which creates many objects?

Comment: I would create an objectFactory per class type. E.g. if my class is 'Automobile', I will have a class called 'AutomobileFactory' with a bunch of static methods e.g. 'createByName(..)' so that the user call call it by saying 'Automobile a = AutomobileFactory.createByName("BMW")'

Comment: The 'createByName(..)' can then go lookup in the database what to do with the name "BMW". I would get all the needed details and construct an Automobile

Answer (score 1):

Another class should probably instantiate the Object by reading the values needed to create it from the database.  This is a better separation of concerns.  The Object which holds the values would probably just be a JavaBean i.e. value holding object.  I certainly wouldn't add database access code to individual objects.

Comment: Okay great that's what I thought, thanks! ~This is how I coded my first application though hehe

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the scenario. But as a rule of thumb, you should try to separate access to database from the object. Personally, I would probably go with a builder class, that has an injectable interface for database access, and would return/build me an object.

Please note, there are many scenarios where it'll be fine to let the object create itself.

Answer (score 1):

If it's sufficiently complex, you could look at implementing a Factory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

I believe that is probably what you were describing in your post with 'another object' that helps in the creation.

Comment: I find the link somewhat hard to follow, but is it saying that you can create a factory which knows how to create various different types of pre-set objects?